# How can i copy the contents of one variable to another using pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
char *foo(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i=0; src[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        dest[i] = src[i];
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return dest;

}
```

I know that the code is moving through both variable's arrays, and while it's doing that, it makes dest[] have the same character as src[]

How can i do this with pointers instead?

Comment: You are already using pointers. There is no operator for accessing array elements (or at least directly). More info on the subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a).

Comment: Provide the declaration of `src` and `dst`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
while (*src != '\0')
    *dst++ = *src++;
*dst = '\0'; // Perhaps you will also need this!
```

Remember at the end of the loop that `dst` is pointing to the end of the array not to the begining. And also copy the `'\0'` terminator, or you don't want to?

Comment: That can be compressed to `while ((*dst++ = *src++));`, although that's probably a little terser than most people are comfortable with.

Comment: i like the way this looks XD. Thank you guys, this solution worked for me.

Comment: `dst[1], *(dst+1), *(1+dst), 1[dst]`. as i remember all these are same and ugly a bit to me :).

Comment: This only works if `src` and `dst` are already pointers. From the given context this is not clear.

Comment: @Olaf edited my question such that it is obvious that we are in fact working with pointers